# arraylist duplicate values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Please help me with my code. i'm using an arraylist named tempAns, it contain values [2, 9, 2]. i've tried adding the last two numbers then replace them with the right answer so the result will be [2, 11]. but somehow, the output was always [9, 11]. it seems like it's deleting duplicate values.

```
   else if(scan.equals("+"))
            {
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1));
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-2));
                double ans = num1 + num2;
                String stringAns = Double.toString(ans);
                System.out.println("before deleting: " +tempAns + "\n");

                tempAns.remove(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1));
                tempAns.remove(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1));

                System.out.println("before adding: " +tempAns);
                tempAns.add(stringAns);
                System.out.println(num1 + " + " +num2+ " = " +ans);
                System.out.println("after deleting: " +tempAns + "\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to consider is that you can consolidate the place where you retrieve num1 and num2 and where you remove them like such:

```
        System.out.println("before deleting: " +tempAns + "\n");
        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(tempAns.remove(tempAns.size()-1));
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(tempAns.remove(tempAns.size()-1));
        double ans = num1 + num2;
        String stringAns = Double.toString(ans);

        System.out.println("before adding: " +tempAns);
        tempAns.add(stringAns);
        System.out.println(num1 + " + " +num2+ " = " +ans);
        System.out.println("after deleting: " +tempAns + "\n");
```

The previous code fixes the issue you were having and may be easier to follow as you are not trying to keep track of the offset where the items are in the list. This is a bit closer to popping the list off a stack and then pushing it back when you calculate the value.

Comment: thank you very much. i'm actually doing stack with the use of an arraylist.

Answer (score 4):

The `remove()` method uses the `equals()` method to find which object should be removed. Then

```
 tempAns.remove(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1));
```

means

```
 tempAns.remove(2);
```

And the first element matches the equals, having the list with `[9, 2]`. Then, calling `tempAns.remove(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1));` again, will remove the other `2`, and the list will be `[9]`.

You can use the `remove(index)` method or use `LinkedList` instead `ArrayList`, and call the `removeLast()` method twice.

Comment: oh, i see. thanks. but how do i fix it? i thought remove(int index_num)

Comment: @TokuchiToua see my answer, you used an inherited method, instead of the one from ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

```
tempAns.remove(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1));
//above remove is evaluated to 
tempAns.remove(2);  // Removes the 2 at index 0
```

The problem is, you are first fetching the value at index 2.. which is 2.
Now you are removing the value 2, which actually removes the `2` at index 0..

You should rather remove by index: -

```
tempAns.remove(tempAns.size()-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 tempAns.remove(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1)); You shold do below
 tempAns.remove(tempAns.size()-1); //remove last
 tempAns.remove(tempAns.size()-1); //remove second last
```

Reason is `tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1)` returns `2` which is also at the start so remove will remove `2` at the start.

[public boolean remove(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the call).

Answer (score 1):

Use `tempAns.remove(tempAns.size()-1)` instead of using `tempAns.remove(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1));`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using the inherited method of remove, from AbstractCollection, when using: `tempAns.remove(tempAns.get(tempAns.size()-1));`. From your description you need the remove from ArrayList, that is using an index, so you should change the call to: `tempAns.remove(tempAns.size()-1);`